# Is there something similar to Rust pattern syntax in R?

Tags: r, rust, switch-statement, pattern-matching

I know of the switch statement in R, but I'm curious if there's a way to assign the same action/value to multiple patterns in the same arm, similar to how it's in Rust:

```
let x = 1;
match x {
    1 | 2 => println!("one or two"),
    3 => println!("three"),
    _ => println!("anything"),
}
```

I don't need to write two separate cases for 1 & 2, I can just combine them into one with '|'. It would be also helpful if I could define the default case ("_") if no pattern before was matched.

Comment: there's no structural pattern matching or algebraic data types in R. so there's nothing similar to Rust pattern syntax in R. The top answer provides something similar to `case` of common lisp, but without destructuring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preceding values with no assignment carry forward until an assigned value is found.

```r
switch(
  as.character(x),
  "1"=,
  "2"="one or two",
  "3"="three",
  "anything"
)
```

I use `as.character(x)` instead of just `x` because `EXPR` (the first argument) may be interpreted as positional instead of equality. From `?switch`:

```
     If the value of 'EXPR' is not a character string it is coerced to
     integer.  Note that this also happens for 'factor's, with a
     warning, as typically the character level is meant.  If the
     integer is between 1 and 'nargs()-1' then the corresponding
     element of '...' is evaluated and the result returned: thus if the
     first argument is '3' then the fourth argument is evaluated and
     returned.
```

So if `x` is an integer between 1 and the number of other arguments, then it is interpreted as a positional indicator, as in

```r
switch(3, 'a','z','y','f')
# [1] "y"
```

which means that the named arguments are effectively ignored, as in this very confusing example

```r
switch(3, '1'='a','3'='z','2'='y','4'='f')
# [1] "y"
```

Note that the help does not reference non-strings that are greater than `nargs()-1` ... those integers return null:

```r
(switch(9, '1'='a','3'='z','2'='y','4'='f'))
# NULL
```

Since it is the *value* of the integer you're looking to match, you need to confusingly convert to string:

```r
switch(as.character(3), '1'='a','3'='z','2'='y','4'='f')
# [1] "z"
```

---

Alternatively,

```r
dplyr::case_when(
  x %in% 1:2 ~ "one or two",
  x == 3     ~ "three",
  TRUE       ~ "anything"
)
# [1] "one or two"
```

or

```r
data.table::fcase(
  x %in% 1:2          , "one or two",
  x == 3              , "three",
  rep(TRUE, length(x)), "anything"
)
```

(The need for `rep(TRUE,length(x))` is because `fcase` requires all arguments to be exactly the same length, i.e., it allows no recycling as many R functions allow. I personally would prefer that they allow `1 or N` recycling instead of `only N`, but that isn't the way at the moment.)

This has an advantage that it is naturally vectorized.

`switch` is only length-1 friendly. A workaround for a vector `x` could be

```r
sapply(x, switch, '1'='a', '3'='z', '2'='y', '4'='f')
```

(or, better yet, `vapply` enforcing the return `class`).

Comment: It doesn't look as clean as in Rust but it'll do the job, thanks. Also, thank you for the nice explanation on why to be mindful about using as.character in this scenario!

Comment: *"Look as clean"* is a common thing in the lisp-y parenthetic "heck" known as R. But it's also subjective and an eye-of-the-beholder, because I find it natural, comfortable, and intuitive ... b/c I've been using it for long enough. BTW, there's always `dplyr::case_when`, let me edit and show you that alternative that might be more aesthetic/intuitive.

Comment: Thank you for dplyr alternative, that one I indeed find more aesthetic.